# Saving settings for batch run in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, batch

I am running a merge and dissolve on a variety of combinations of 9 different shapefiles, 3 at a time.

I made a model in the model builder that takes 3 inputs and performs a merge and then a dissolve.

I had a go at trying to make the iterator work but really i'd need more than one to make it work so I'll need to use batch anyway.

Basically, is there a way to save the settings on a batch run so that it can be repeated another time? Later on I might need to change some of the decisions we made on the initial shapefiles (the ones that are being merged) and it would be great if there was a single click button to repeat the action.

Alternatively, is there any way to import batch settings from excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled a lot like you before finding this by sheer luck some month ago. Below is a very easy trick for saving batch configuration:

- Select all your lines in the batch editor
- Copy lines with shortcut Ctrl + C or right click + Copy
- Paste in Excel
- Optionaly modify whatever
- Save

[image: Copy to Excel]

**Later**

- Open your Excel document
- Open a new batch editor.
- Create at least the same number of lines or more the empty batch form
- Select all your batch data in Excel
- Select all your lines in the batch interface
- Paste into the batch editor with shortcut Ctrl + V or Right click + Paste

It's as simple as that :)

[image: Copy back into Arcgis]

Comment: oh nice one thanks.
arc is so un-user-friendly it's insane. so many great features are impossible to find!
also took me ages to figure out that you need to click the row numbers on the far left to highlight a full row at a time rather than being able to highlight cells inside the table

Comment: Indeed ! In the same type of tricks, it took me really a long time (lots and lots of copy paste) to find out the "Fill" option (right click + Fill) to copy the same parameter downwards automatically !!

Answer (score 2):

Create a model, save all settings and run it. Go to meny Geoprocessing - Results, right click the model (under Current Session), save as result file. The resultfile can be used to run the model again with all settings the same.

[image]

Comment: this is what i'm doing at the moment. what i'm interested in is if there's a way to save the inputs to the batch run so it can be repeated at a later date. it's not urgent really but would be a good feature

Comment: You can save it in the model. Double-click on Input Datasets, set them and save model.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. but i managed to reduce the amount of runs I need to put into the batch by setting up an iterator on some of them, so it's all sorted

Comment: The edit you made is a great feature! Results > Re-Run is awesome I'll definitely use that a lot